# Use an Excel macro to change colour of a column if a column contains a specific word

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up a macro to change the colour of cells based on the value of a specific column.

However, I only want to search for one word in the string, as some of the strings contain the same word but different models.

So far I have this script, but it doesn't work unless I punch in the FULL STRING from column D.

```
Sub ColorMacro()
   Dim i As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range
   For i = "2" To "180"
      Set r1 = Range("D" & i)
      Set r2 = Range("A" & i & ":O" & i)
      If r1.Value = "CERATO" Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
      If r1.Value = "NIRO" Then r2.Interior.Color = vbBlue
      If r1.Value = "PICANTO" Then r2.Interior.Color = vbYellow
   Next i
End Sub
```

How can I get this code to just look for the specific word, as opposed to the whole string?

String Eg: BD PE CERATO SEDAN S A/T S/P and BD PE CERATO HATCH S A/T S/P can be the same colour, so I only want it to change if it says CERATO.

Comment: Why vba? have you tried conditional formatting?

Comment: I understand Conditional Formatting even less than I do VBA, I don't know where to even begin setting up a Conditional Format that will allow me to change Cells Ax:Ox depending on what Dx contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Format Interior

**Using Conditional Formatting (Updates on Changes)**

1. Select the complete range, e.g. `A2:O180`.
2. Select `Conditional Formatting > New Rule`
3. In the `New Formatting Rule` window select `Use a formula to determine which cells to format` and in the text box below `Format values where this formula is true:` input the formula:

   ```
   =SEARCH("Cerato",$D2)>0
   ```
4. Click `Format` and in the `Format Cells` window select the `Fill` tab, pick the appropriate color and click `OK` to close the `Format Cells` window.
5. Click `OK` to close the `New Formatting Rule` window.
6. Repeat the process for the other models (`Niro`, `Picanto`,... etc.).

**Using VBA (One Time, No Updates)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColorFormatModels()
    
    Const ModelsList As String = "Cerato,Niro,Picanto"
    Const sColumn As String = "D"
    Const dColumns As String = "A:O"
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    Const lRow As Long = 180 ' Out-comment this if you want to...***
    
    ' The number of elements in Colors has to be equal to the number
    ' of comma-separated substrings in the Models List.
    Dim Colors As Variant: Colors = VBA.Array(vbRed, vbBlue, vbYellow)
    
    Dim Models() As String: Models = Split(ModelsList, ",")
    Dim nUpper As Long: nUpper = UBound(Models)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ' ***... dynamically determine the last row:
    'Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, sColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = ws.Range(ws.Cells(fRow, sColumn), ws.Cells(lRow, sColumn))
    ' Clear previous color formats:
    srg.EntireRow.Columns(dColumns).Interior.Color = xlNone
     
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        For n = 0 To nUpper
            If InStr(1, sCell, Models(n), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                sCell.EntireRow.Columns(dColumns).Interior.Color = Colors(n)
                Exit For ' found, go to next cell
            End If
        Next n
    Next sCell
    
    MsgBox "Colors applied.", vbInformation, "Color Format Models"
    
End Sub
```